# Why do links in gmail redirect?

Tags: security, redirect

I've noticed that some email services (like gmail or my school's webmail) will redirect links (or used to) in the email body. So when I put "www.google.com" in the body of my email, and I check that email in gmail or something, the link says something like "gmail.com/redirect?www.google.com".

This was very confusing for me and the people I emailed (like my parents, who are not familiar with computers). I always clicked on the link anyway, but why is this service used? (I'm also worried that maybe my information was being sent somewhere... Do I have anything to worry about? Is something being stored before the redirect?)

Sorry if this is unwarranted paranoia. I am just curious about why some things work the way they do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This redirection is a [dereferrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer) to avoid disclosure of the URL in the HTTP *Referer* field to third party sites as that URL can contain sensitive data like a session ID.

Comment: I don't think that's right... Gmail's urls do not include session ids, right?

Comment: Do you really think that is the reason? That google wants to help you keep non-tracked? Isnt it more likely that they want to monetize tracking YOU.

Comment: this is insane!, im using service workers so my customers can access my links without internet connection and since links go through google first is not working!

Comment: can we disable this by any means?

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia has a good article on [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection). From the article:

> Logging outgoing links
>
> The access logs
>   of most web servers keep detailed
>   information about where visitors came
>   from and how they browsed the hosted
>   site. They do not, however, log which
>   links visitors left by. This is
>   because the visitor's browser has no
>   need to communicate with the original
>   server when the visitor clicks on an
>   outgoing link. This information can be
>   captured in several ways. One way
>   involves URL redirection. Instead of
>   sending the visitor straight to the
>   other site, links on the site can
>   direct to a URL on the original
>   website's domain that automatically
>   redirects to the real target. This
>   technique bears the downside of the
>   delay caused by the additional request
>   to the original website's server. As
>   this added request will leave a trace
>   in the server log, revealing exactly
>   which link was followed, it can also
>   be a privacy issue.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) The same
>   technique is also used by some
>   corporate websites to implement a
>   statement that the subsequent content
>   is at another site, and therefore not
>   necessarily affiliated with the
>   corporation. In such scenarios,
>   displaying the warning causes an
>   additional delay.

So, yes, Google (and Facebook and Twitter do this to) are logging where your services are taking you. This is important for a variety of reasons - it lets them know how their service is being used, shows trends in data, allows links to be monetized, etc.

As far as your concerns, my personal opinion is that, if you're on the internet, you're being tracked. All the time. If this is concerning to you, I would recommend communicating differently. However, for the most part, I think it's not worth worrying about.