# Gmail breaking link with tracking

Tags: email, html-email, gmail-api, amazon-ses

We are sending html emails through amazon ses. It appears that gmail is altering the href tag and making it unusable. It almost looks like it's putting tracking information there instead of the original link. Below is what we are sending to ses and what we see in the client's email. It is happening for all href tags in the email, but not every email going to gmail.

Sending to ses:
`<a ses:no-track href="http://www.Google.com">www.Google.com</a>`

Client email:
`<a href="http://esfsecev-ty3014" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://esfsecev-ty3014&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1541799752348000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHRj6rzLaQFMfQQPtoDE_Q9RTTFQQ">
www.GoSurvey.com</a>`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: im having a similar error, I found some info about whats going on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172168/why-do-links-in-gmail-redirect
But i haven't found a way to fix it.